# How to install JRE patch

Tags: java

I would like to install [this java patch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u75-relnotes-2389086.html) to an existing JDK.
How do I install this?

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just look at the sky and when you see a Comet in the sky make a wish from bottom of your heart, and this java patch will be installed :)

Comment: What patch? Sun/Oracle have never released patches for existing versions and your link certainly does not point to one.

Comment: @Luminous Other software products are frequently updated through patches instead of full redownloads.  This question is not unreasonable if you are familiar with those and new to the Java platform in the Oracle flavor.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Woah. Did you delete my comment?

Comment: @Luminous no.  A moderator most likely did if he/she considered your comment rude or offensive.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle JRE is not released as patches, but as releases.

You need to download and install the new version.

Comment: thanks this was the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I am just curious how do they release the security fixes? then what is JRE update? https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml#install

Comment: JRE update simply asks Oracle on a regular basis if a newer version is available than the one currently running and if yes, prompts the user to install the new version.   Note that an auto-updater is - as far as I know - forthcoming but I don't think it is ready for non-developer use yet.

Comment: @user1493834 exactly as the name describes. It is an update of a previous version. But where you read "update", you assume "patch". But another way to apply an update is to simply completely replace an existing installation with a new one, which is what the java runtime updater does.